# Error building LEGO Mindstorms EV3 project in MATLAB / Simulink on Linux

Tags: matlab, simulink, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I am trying to build a simple project for EV3 hardware using Simulink. When trying to build the model, i get the error

```
Code generation information file does not exist.
```

I have searched everywhere and found people having similar issues due to space characters in their paths. None of the solutions worked for my case though. Any tips on building Mindstorms projects on Linux would be appreciated.
Here are the full logs:

```
### Starting build procedure for: legomann
"/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc" -c -MMD -MP -MF"legomann.dep" -MT"legomann.o" -O0 -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/include -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/include-fixed -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lms2012.instrset/EV3Source -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lmstypes.instrset/EV3Source -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_bytecodes.instrset/EV3Source -c -nostdinc -D__MW_TARGET_USE_HARDWARE_RESOURCES_H__ -D_RTT_LCD_=1 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0  -DTID01EQ=0 -D__linux__ -DARM_PROJECT -D_USE_TARGET_UDP_ -D_RUNONTARGETHARDWARE_BUILD_ -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DRT -DMODEL=legomann -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -DMODEL_HAS_DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_SFCNS=0 -I/home/magnus/teknostart -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/include -I/home/magnus/teknostart/legomann_ert_rtw -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/ert -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lmstypes.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lms2012.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_bytecodes.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/toolbox/coder/rtiostream/src/utils -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/toolbox/target/codertarget/rtos/inc -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/src -o "legomann.o" "/home/magnus/teknostart/legomann_ert_rtw/legomann.c"
"/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc" -c -MMD -MP -MF"legomann_data.dep" -MT"legomann_data.o" -O0 -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/include -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/include-fixed -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lms2012.instrset/EV3Source -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lmstypes.instrset/EV3Source -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_bytecodes.instrset/EV3Source -c -nostdinc -D__MW_TARGET_USE_HARDWARE_RESOURCES_H__ -D_RTT_LCD_=1 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0  -DTID01EQ=0 -D__linux__ -DARM_PROJECT -D_USE_TARGET_UDP_ -D_RUNONTARGETHARDWARE_BUILD_ -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DRT -DMODEL=legomann -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -DMODEL_HAS_DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_SFCNS=0 -I/home/magnus/teknostart -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/include -I/home/magnus/teknostart/legomann_ert_rtw -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/ert -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lmstypes.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lms2012.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_bytecodes.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/toolbox/coder/rtiostream/src/utils -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/toolbox/target/codertarget/rtos/inc -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/src -o "legomann_data.o" "/home/magnus/teknostart/legomann_ert_rtw/legomann_data.c"
"/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc" -c -MMD -MP -MF"linuxinitialize.dep" -MT"linuxinitialize.o" -O0 -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/include -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/include-fixed -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lms2012.instrset/EV3Source -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lmstypes.instrset/EV3Source -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_bytecodes.instrset/EV3Source -c -nostdinc -D__MW_TARGET_USE_HARDWARE_RESOURCES_H__ -D_RTT_LCD_=1 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0  -DTID01EQ=0 -D__linux__ -DARM_PROJECT -D_USE_TARGET_UDP_ -D_RUNONTARGETHARDWARE_BUILD_ -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DRT -DMODEL=legomann -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -DMODEL_HAS_DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_SFCNS=0 -I/home/magnus/teknostart -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/include -I/home/magnus/teknostart/legomann_ert_rtw -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/ert -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lmstypes.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lms2012.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_bytecodes.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/toolbox/coder/rtiostream/src/utils -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/toolbox/target/codertarget/rtos/inc -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/src -o "linuxinitialize.o" "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/toolbox/target/codertarget/rtos/src/linuxinitialize.c"
"/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc" -c -MMD -MP -MF"driver_ev3_button.dep" -MT"driver_ev3_button.o" -O0 -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/include -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/include-fixed -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lms2012.instrset/EV3Source -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lmstypes.instrset/EV3Source -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_bytecodes.instrset/EV3Source -c -nostdinc -D__MW_TARGET_USE_HARDWARE_RESOURCES_H__ -D_RTT_LCD_=1 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0  -DTID01EQ=0 -D__linux__ -DARM_PROJECT -D_USE_TARGET_UDP_ -D_RUNONTARGETHARDWARE_BUILD_ -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DRT -DMODEL=legomann -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -DMODEL_HAS_DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_SFCNS=0 -I/home/magnus/teknostart -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/include -I/home/magnus/teknostart/legomann_ert_rtw -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/ert -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lmstypes.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lms2012.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_bytecodes.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/toolbox/coder/rtiostream/src/utils -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/toolbox/target/codertarget/rtos/inc -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/src -o "driver_ev3_button.o" "/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/src/driver_ev3_button.c"
/bin/sh: 1: /home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
/bin/sh: 1: /home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
"/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc" -c -MMD -MP -MF"driver_ev3_lcd.dep" -MT"driver_ev3_lcd.o" -O0 -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/include -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/include-fixed -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lms2012.instrset/EV3Source -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lmstypes.instrset/EV3Source -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_bytecodes.instrset/EV3Source -c -nostdinc -D__MW_TARGET_USE_HARDWARE_RESOURCES_H__ -D_RTT_LCD_=1 -DCLASSIC_INTERFACE=0 -DALLOCATIONFCN=0 -DONESTEPFCN=1 -DTERMFCN=1 -DMULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 -DINTEGER_CODE=0 -DMT=0  -DTID01EQ=0 -D__linux__ -DARM_PROJECT -D_USE_TARGET_UDP_ -D_RUNONTARGETHARDWARE_BUILD_ -DSTACK_SIZE=64 -DRT -DMODEL=legomann -DNUMST=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DHAVESTDIO -DMODEL_HAS_DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_SFCNS=0 -I/home/magnus/teknostart -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/include -I/home/magnus/teknostart/legomann_ert_rtw -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/simulink/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/src -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/rtw/c/ert -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lmstypes.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_lms2012.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcecode_bytecodes.instrset/EV3Source/.. -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/toolbox/coder/rtiostream/src/utils -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023a/toolbox/target/codertarget/rtos/inc -I/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/src -o "driver_ev3_lcd.o" "/home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/toolbox/target/supportpackages/ev3/src/driver_ev3_lcd.c"
/bin/sh: 1: /home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
gmake: *** [legomann.o] Error 127
gmake: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [legomann_data.o] Error 127
gmake: *** [linuxinitialize.o] Error 127
/bin/sh: 1: /home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
/bin/sh: 1: /home/magnus/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2023a/3P.instrset/ev3sourcerylite.instrset/arm-2009q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
gmake: *** [driver_ev3_button.o] Error 127
gmake: *** [driver_ev3_lcd.o] Error 127
### Build procedure for legomann aborted due to an error.
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue. My problem was that the EV3 toolbox for Simulink operated with 32-bit binaries, but my system had support for 64-bit only. Installing `ia32-libs-multiarch` fixed the issue.

Comment: great! Also, some software can have problems with dots in the filenames, this is why `_` underscore is very common in filepaths